# jQuery detect if mouse clicked between mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I am making a small script for a rating system and currently have 3 functions:

1. onhover:

   ```
   a. On mouse enter change the color of div depending on value
   b. On mouse leave revert back to white
   ```
2. onclick:

   ```
   a. On click save color change and put value in another div
   ```

   Now I need to check if one of the divs has been clicked before the mouseleave because I need the color to stay the same as when mouseclicked when you leave the div if you selected it.

How would I check for that?

Here's my div construction:

```
<div class='rating' data-target="tijd">
    <div class='circle'>1</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>2</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>3</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>4</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>5</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>6</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>7</div>//green
    <div class='circle'>8</div>//white
    <div class='circle'>9</div>//white
    <div class='circle'>10</div>//white
    <div class='score'><span id="tijd">7</span></div>
</div>
```

so `$('.circle').on('hover', function(e){}, function(e){})` and then `$('.circle').on('click', function(e){})` so the click function gets overwritten by the mouse-leave function because the mouseleave function gets called later.

in the "#tijd" span  I save the value of the div you clicked, and on hover I need every div that is smaller than or equal to the span to change to a certain color while everything that is bigger than that value is white, and if you don't click anything the divs should be colored again using the value that is still in the span.

( I have tried checking if the div that hold the value on click isn't empty but it never is )

```js
$('.circle').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings().css('background-color', 'white')
  val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
  $(this).prevAll('.circle').each(function() {
    if (val < 4 && val > 0)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    if (val < 7 && val > 3)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'orange')
    if (val < 11 && val > 6)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
  })
  val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
  console.log(val)
  if (val < 4 && val > 0)
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
  if (val < 7 && val > 3)
    $(this).css('background-color', 'orange')
  if (val < 11 && val > 6)
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
}, function(e) {
  spanid = spanid = $(this).parent().attr('data-target')
  text = $('#' + spanid).text()
  console.log(text)
  if ($('#' + spanid) == '') {
    $(this).siblings('.circle').css('background-color', 'white')
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white')
  } else {
    val = parseInt(text, 10)
    if (val < 4 && val > 0)
      color = 'red'
    if (val < 7 && val > 3)
      color = 'orange'
    if (val < 11 && val > 6)
      color = 'green'
    $(this).prevAll('.circle').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() <= text) {
        console.log('smaller or equal to')
        next.css('background-color', color)
      }
      if (text.val() == "") {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white')

      } else {
        console.log('bigger')
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white')
      }
    })
  }
})
$('.circle').click(function(e) {
  console.log('get clicked')
  spanid = $(this).parent().attr('data-target')
  val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
  $('#' + spanid).text(val)
  console.log('Value = ' + val)
  next = $('#' + spanid).parent()
  if (val < 4 && val > 0)
    color = 'red'
  if (val < 7 && val > 3)
    color = 'orange'
  if (val < 11 && val > 6)
    color = 'green'
  next.css('background-color', color)
  $(this).prevAll('.circle').css('background-color', color)

})
```

```css
.reviews {
  background-color: white;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.rating {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.circle {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
  <label>Tarief</label>
  <div class='rating' data-target="tarief">
    <div class='circle'>1</div>
    <div class='circle'>2</div>
    <div class='circle'>3</div>
    <div class='circle'>4</div>
    <div class='circle'>5</div>
    <div class='circle'>6</div>
    <div class='circle'>7</div>
    <div class='circle'>8</div>
    <div class='circle'>9</div>
    <div class='circle'>10</div>
    <div class='score'><span id="tarief"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
  <label>Reactietijd en bereikbaarheid</label>
  <div class='rating' data-target="tijd">
    <div class='circle'>1</div>
    <div class='circle'>2</div>
    <div class='circle'>3</div>
    <div class='circle'>4</div>
    <div class='circle'>5</div>
    <div class='circle'>6</div>
    <div class='circle'>7</div>
    <div class='circle'>8</div>
    <div class='circle'>9</div>
    <div class='circle'>10</div>
    <div class='score'><span id="tijd"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but how does an element trigger the `click` event without having triggered the `hover` event first?

In my opinion if an element is `click`ed, it should be already on `hover`.

Comment: it is, but the problem is that the click event gets overwritten by the hoverout event

Comment: Lol, where are your semicolons man. Your syntax is poor. Look at the examples below.

Comment: @magreenberg I'm sorry but did you know that jquery doesn't need semicolons?

Comment: Yea, jquery is a javascript library. You need to end statements with a semi colon. There are some cases where you dont need it, but it doesn't hurt to put them in anyway.

Comment: @FMashiro: jQuery is a library of functions, not a language. Writing JavaScript requires correct use of semicolons. JavaScript does provide an *error-correction mechanism* called Automatic Semicolon Insertion which will try to fix code with missing semicolons, but that's exactly what it is: An error-correction mechanism. (That's from the horse's mouth, Brendan Eich, creator and still chief maintainer of the language.)

Comment: Alright then I didn't realize that, 'll start adding them in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with CSS and a class:

1. Use a CSS `:hover` rule to set the color for when the mouse cursor is over the element
2. On click, set a class on the element to indicate that it's been selected
3. Style the element based on that class

**Example:**

```js
$(document.body).on("click", ".rating > .circle", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.rating {
  padding: 2px;
}
.rating .circle {
  padding: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

/* When hovering, use a yellow background */
.rating > .circle:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Selected items have a blue background and white text */
.rating > .circle.selected,
.rating > .circle.selected:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <div class="circle">2</div>
  <div class="circle">3</div>
  <div class="circle">4</div>
  <div class="circle">5</div>
  <div class="circle">6</div>
  <div class="circle">7</div>
  <div class="circle">8</div>
  <div class="circle">9</div>
  <div class="circle">10</div>
</div>
<div class="rating">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <div class="circle">2</div>
  <div class="circle">3</div>
  <div class="circle">4</div>
  <div class="circle">5</div>
  <div class="circle">6</div>
  <div class="circle">7</div>
  <div class="circle">8</div>
  <div class="circle">9</div>
  <div class="circle">10</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the hoverout event would still overwrite the click event

Comment: @FMashiro: No, it won't. See the example.

Comment: See my snippet for what I mean

Comment: @FMashiro: The solution above works. Try it. You don't have to use it if for some reason you don't want to, but it *does* work. To do the color thing you're doing requires only a tiny amount of tweaking.

Comment: I'll rewrite my code to fit this in thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

suppose the element's default background color is defined as

```
div.rating .circle
{
   background-color: #000; 
}
```

on hover color changes to

```
div.rating .circle:hover
{
   background-color: #ff0; 
}
```

at the click event set another class 'selected' so when the mouse leaves color changes to `#dedede;`

```
$( "div.rating .circle" ).click( function(){

   $( this ).toggleClass( "selected" );

} );

div.rating .circle.selected
{
   background-color: #dedede; 
}
```

define the hover behaviour for `selected` class as well

```
div.rating .circle.selected:hover
{
   background-color: #dedede; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding and removing a class on mouse enter and mouse leave and checking against that class when clicking would be a convenient way.

```
//add and remove a focus class with the same css values as the active class
$('.yourclass').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('.yourclass').addClass('focussed');
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.yourclass').removeClass('focussed');
});

//check only for clicks on the focussed element and add the active class
$('.yourclass.focussed').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the `.click()` function to your jQuery like so:

#### Note that all of this is example code

## HTML

```
<div class="colors">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="pink"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
.blue {
  background-color:blue;
}
.green {
  background-color:green;
}
.yellow {
  background-color:yellow;
}
.pink {
  background-color:pink;
}
div {
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
}
div.colors {
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
}
```

## jQuery**

```
$( "div" ).not('.colors')
.mouseenter(function() {
    //do something
   })
.mouseleave(function() {
    //do something
  })
.click(function() {
  var color = $(this).css('background-color');
  alert(color);
});
```

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1tz5vrdo/1/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquerys .hover() function instead of mousein mouseout.

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxy">

</div>

<div class="selected">
  <h1>Selected Color From Click</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.boxy{
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.selected{
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

**JS**

```
var colors = ["#34f23a", "#f8f8f1", "#31b1cc"];
var changecolors;
var colorIndex = 0;

$('.boxy').hover(function(){
  shuffle = true;
  $(this).css('background', colors[colorIndex]);
  changecolors = setInterval(function(){
    if (colorIndex < (colors.length - 1)){
      colorIndex += 1;
    } else {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
    $('.boxy').css('background', colors[colorIndex]);
  },500);

}, function(){
  window.clearInterval(changecolors);
  $('.boxy').css('background', 'transparent');
});

$('.boxy').click(function(){
   var selectedColor = $(this).css('background');
   $('.selected').css('background', selectedColor);
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kf7516kg/)

Comment: That is what I did, except that's where the problem is, check out the snippet I added

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>js functions</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color:#101010; color: #aaa; text-align: center;}
    #holder{ width: 100%; height:100px; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;}
    #hover { position: relative; border: 1px dashed #333; width:100px; height:100px; display: inline-block;}
    #save  { border: 1px dashed #333; width:100px; height:100px; display: inline-block;}
  </style>
  <script>
    document.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      
      var hover = document.getElementById("hover");
      var save  = document.getElementById("save");

      hover.onmouseover = function()
      {
        hover.style.background = "#f00";
      };

      hover.onmouseout = function()
      {
        hover.style.background = "#101010";
      };

      hover.onclick = function()
      {
        save.style.background = "#fff";
      };
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder">
  <div id="hover">hover</div><div id="save">save</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```